# find count of rows added for clicked element

Tags: jquery

i have a table when i want a option of 'add row', but i want rows to be added doe the same row, ie, using rowspan. now i want the rowspan number to be incremented according to the number of times i click on the add row button FOR THAT ELEMENT.

HTML:

```
 <table class="table table-bordered datatabl dt-responsive">

      <thead>
      <tr>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <!-- <th>Billing Status</th> -->
      <th>Skills</th>
      <th>Experience (in Years)</th>
      <th>Head Count</th>
      <!-- <th>Billing State</th> -->
      <th>Action</th>
      </tr>

      </thead>
      <tbody>


      <tr>
      <td class=""><a href="javascript:void(0);">Feb</a>
      <div class="popverdiv col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <label>From</label>
        <select class="form-control">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
        </select>

      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <label>To</label>
        <select class="form-control">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
        </select>

      </div>

      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></i>

      <div class="popverdiv-buttons">
      <a class="btn btn-primary setastraveldates">Set Date</a>
      <a class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
      </div>
      </div>
      </td>

      <td><select class="form-control skil"><option>Select</option><option>HTML</option><option>JAVA</option></select></td>
      <td><select class="form-control exp"><option>Select</option><option>1-3</option><option>3-5</option></select></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control headcount"/></td>

      <td>
   <select class="form-control">
      <option>Select</option>
      <option>Copy to Next</option>
      <option>Copy to all</option>
    </select>

    <a class="addrow">+</a>



     </td>

      </tr>




      </tbody>
      </table>
```

JS:

```
 $(".addrow").on("click",function(){
    $(this).parents("tr").after('<tr class="rowadded" role="row" class="odd"><td tabindex="0"><span class="">Jan</span></td><td><select class="form-control skil"><option>Select</option><option>HTML</option><option>JAVA</option></select></td><td><select class="form-control exp"><option>Select</option><option>1-3</option><option>3-5</option></select></td><td class="sorting_1"><input type="text" class="form-control headcount"></td><td><select class="form-control"><option>Select</option><option>Copy to Next</option><option>Copy to all</option></select></td></tr>');


    var i =0;
    $(this).parents("tr").next(".rowadded").each(function(){
    i++;

    });
    console.log(i);
    });
```

but my code is not counting the no. of times 'rowadded' class is added next to the row where addrow button is there, and reset the count for the next addrow button. Pls help.

Comment: jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f9L3v9xq/

Answer (score 0):

Try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f9L3v9xq/1/)

```
var i =0;
$(".rowadded").each(function(){
i++;

});
console.log(i);
```

Check in console will show the actual number of rows been added.

Comment: Arunkumar G, there is a problem in your fiddle. if you add 2 rows already, and then click on the add button of first row 2 times and then click on the add row button of 2nd row, the count will be 3, whereas it should be one. that is why i said about the 'reset' in the question.

Comment: add button in your code is static and not dynamically getting added to the new rows created. So, at any time if we click on add row button we will get the total number of clicks only and not by the row specific clicks. Maybe i'm not getting your requirement. Please elaborate more.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `length` instead of `each` like below:

```
$(this).parents("tr").next(".rowadded").length;  //returns 1
$('.rowadded').length; //returns total count
```

Comment: please accept the answer or upvote if helped you? @user3450590

Comment: sorry this seems wrong because $('.rowadded').length returns the length of .rowadded in all the table, which is wrong

Comment: what you are trying also same..using each you are incrementing the varaiable @user3450590